# Replicate atomic coordinates in x, y direction

Tags: plotting, graphics, geometric-transform

I have x and y coordinates of a lattice. I want to replicate the system in x and y directions.
Can you please guide me on this.[image]

Comment: Please include the coordinates and the rules to generate them, preferably as Mathematica code. Also what kind of output do you seek? A list? A plot?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To get started:1) take [the introductory tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour),2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up [by clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

**Generating points**

To replicate the point at the coordinates you have shown, I use a a built-in  function.

```
ptsLattice = Flatten[#, 1] &@CoordinateBoundsArray[{{3, 8}, {-1, 2}}]
```

To find the bounds,

```
rectOrig = Rectangle @@ Transpose@CoordinateBounds[ptsLattice]
```

and to plot these together:

```
Graphics[{
  Red, AbsolutePointSize[5]
  , Point /@ ptsLattice
  , Lighter@Yellow, Opacity[0.4]
  , EdgeForm[{Thin, Dashed, Black}]
  , rectOrig
  }
 , Frame -> True
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image]

This was a brief introduction to the `Coordinate*` commands. At this point I would like to say that you can generate lattice points over an x-y range with the arrangement shown above, instead of replicating them.

---

**Replicating points**

In case you do have to replicate points in the x-y direction, you need to use `TranslationTransform`.

```
replPts = 
 Flatten[#, 1] &@
  Table[TranslationTransform[{x, y}]@ptsLattice, {x, 0, 20, 7}, {y, 1,
     15, 6}]

ListPlot[replPts
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , Frame -> True
 , Axes -> False
 , ImageSize -> Large
 ]
```

[image]

If you want the points to be the same color, just flatten one more level of the
`replPts`. I have left it as such so you can visually see where the points have landed after the transformation. Of course you can and will have to adjust the offsets in the x-y directions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative answer. Appreciate it.